# CardsLib with SpinnerWheel libraries - getting width and height must be > 0 on swipe

Tags: android

Im building an application that uses both libraries android-spinnerwheel & cardsLib.
SpinnerWheel works just fine, but when I try to use swipe to delete feature of cardsLib, something messes with the spinnerWheel.
The error is this:

```
06-21 10:43:04.873  17102-17102/com.bitcoinwatcher.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
            at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:638)
            at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:620)
            at antistatic.spinnerwheel.AbstractWheelView.recreateAssets(AbstractWheelView.java:185)
            at antistatic.spinnerwheel.AbstractWheel.onLayout(AbstractWheel.java:457)
```

I think I somehow need to tell the wheel its being deleted, yet I couldnt find out how exactly.
Even If I manage to do so, It happens before my implementation occurs:

```
    @Override
    public void onSwipe(Card card) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUndoSwipe(Card card) {
    }
}
```

Comment: The error says width and height must be > 0. Have you checked that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, The solution is quite easy.
It appears that CardsLib continuously draws the slider even when not visible, causing it to draw with bitmap width/height of 0.
Adding the following safety check

```
if (width == 0 || height == 0)
    return;
```

to `AbstractWheelView.java` fixes the issue.
so in conclusion,

```
protected void recreateAssets(int width, int height) {
    if (width == 0 || height == 0)
        return;
    mSpinBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mSeparatorsBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    setSelectorPaintCoeff(0);
}
```